# Is it okay to refer a chess product?

Tags: discussion

I know that in stackoverflow, it's forbidden to share link to commercial products, because it's considered as advertising.

I would like to know if it's okay(not considered as advertising) to refer a chess product in chess.stackexchange.

I see some questions/answers are referring some books already, without penalization. But because of the policy of stackoverflow, I wanted to sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is allowed, as long as you disclose your affiliation with the product (if any):

> The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it
>   as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen
>   to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must
>   disclose your affiliation in your answers.

From https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/promotion